# Splitting data from one column into multiple rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am a beginner in SQL and unfortunately I am not being able to solve a problem. I have a list of column names in a system table which I want to insert into separate rows of a table based on the serial of the column name.

Original table:

| Column name |
| --- |
| 001000 |
| 001100 |
| 001200 |
| 002000 |
| 002100 |
| 002200 |
| 002300 |

Target table:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001000 | 001100 | 001200 | NULL |
| 002000 | 002100 | 002200 | 002300 |
| ...... | ...... | ...... | ...... |
| 022000 | 022100 | 022200 | 022300 |

There are a large number of rows in the original table so it is quite challenging to separate the numbers into groups. I have looked into the PIVOT function but that does not solve this issue.

Unfortunately, as I am a beginner, I am also not able to put it into code to begin with. Any help with recommending which functions I should look into so that I can start writing some code on this would be really helpful. Any pointers towards a solution is also highly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Conditional aggregation should do what you want:

```
select max(case when seqnum = 1 then column end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then column end),
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then column end),
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then column end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(column, 3) order by column) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by left(column, 3)
```